# Is there any difference between "Nein Idee" and "keine Ahnung" and when we use " keine Ahnung" and "Nein Idee"

Tags: english-to-german

I am very confused with learning German because "keine Ahnung" means in English "No Idea" and "nein" means "no" and "idea" in German "**Idee**" so why we are not using "nein Idee" on behalf of "keine Ahnung" and when we use "keine Ahnung" and when we use "nein Idee?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The English "no" can be translated to different similar but not interchangeable words in German:

- no, thanks -- nein danke
- no clue -- keine Ahnung
- do not open -- nicht öffnen

Because "nein" can only be used as an answer to a question or to protest something, you cannot say "nein Idee". In this case you need to use "kein(e)", which quantifies something, saying there is none of it.

As a general rule, do not try to translate word by word. "Keine Idee" would be an answer in a brainstorming-like activity where new ideas are expected. To say "no clue", use "keine Ahnung".

A [good dictionary](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/no) should explain the differences.

Comment: Learners of German should pay attention that *keine Ahnung* can savely be used only in non-formal settings, e.g. with friends, family, and very close colleagues. In a formal setting - usually at the work place and with superiors or strangers - it may probably be seen as rude.

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that "Keine Ahnung" and "Keine Idee" are both implicitly bringing their own "Ich habe" (I have) with them which is simply being omitted in spoken conversations.

This does also explain why "Nein Idee" does not make any sense. Just add the part "Ich habe" and the phrase would be "Ich habe nein Idee". Doesn't work ;-)

Both forms (Keine Ahnung, keine Idee) can be used in the same situations.

*My personal opinion*: "Keine Ahnung" to me is more related to previous experiences (Do you know why the system shuts down when performing xyz? - Keine Ahnung.) while "Keine Idee" could better relate to new situations / solutions (What could we do to prevent the system shutting down when performing xyz? - Keine Idee.).

As Christian stated already, both are colloquial and should be used with consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Keine means "no" in the sense of "none."

Ich habe kein Geld.
Ich habe keine Ahnung. 
Ich habe keine Idee.

Nein means "no" in the sense of "not."
Sie wird mein Mädl, nein. (Sie wird mein Mädel, nicht.)

Answer (score 0):

The English word 'no' can be translated to German two different ways depending on context;  keine and nein. Keine is used in a sentence to show quantity. E.g. Ich habe keine Kinder. I have no children. Nein is used in a sentence to usually answer a question, like ' Would you like to go to the party?' 'Not sure how to say that in German' 'No'. 'Nein'.
Now for idee and ahnung. Idee is used when you have an idea or thought that you may like to share. E.g. 'ich habe ein Idee!' 'I have an idea!' Whereas ahnung is used when you don't have an inkling to solve a situation at hand I guess? Not sure if that last example makes sense.